# Deploy Metadata with Apex Testing Using REST error

Tags: rest-api, deployment, metadata-api, httprequest, deployment-api

I'm trying to deploy some ApexClass **from Apex to Production Org** using multipart/forma-data to `/services/data/v48.0/metadata/deployRequest` following [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_rest_deploy.htm).

In the documentation is this example:

```
POST /services/data/v48.0/metadata/deployRequest
Authorization: Bearer 00D....
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------BOUNDARY
----------------------------BOUNDARY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="json"
Content-Type: application/json
{ 
    "deployOptions" :
        {
        "allowMissingFiles" : false,
        "autoUpdatePackage" : false,
        "checkOnly" : false,
        "ignoreWarnings" : false,
        "performRetrieve" : false,
        "purgeOnDelete" : false,
        "rollbackOnError" : false,
        "runTests" : null,
        "singlePackage" : true,
        "testLevel" : "RunAllTestsInOrg"
        }
    }
----------------------------BOUNDARY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="deploy.zip"
Content-Type: application/zip
 
//Contents of deploy.zip
----------------------------BOUNDARY--
```

### The error

```
"message": "Cannot include more than one non-binary part",
"errorCode": "INVALID_MULTIPART_REQUEST"
```

So I tried to do it from localhost (using Insomnia) and got the same error.

### My steps

**1. create deployment package, zip and encode with base64:**

```
src2/
├── classes
│   ├── SomeClass.cls
│   └── SomeClass.cls-meta.xml
└── package.xml
```

```
zip -r deploy.zip src2/ 
cat deploy.zip | base64
```

```
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
```

**2. Set two values in header:**
Authorization -> Bearer ****
Content-Type -> multipart/form-data;  boundary=--------------------------BOUNDARY

**3. Set body:**

```
----------------------------BOUNDARY
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="json"

{
    "deployOptions" :
        {
        "allowMissingFiles" : false,
        "autoUpdatePackage" : false,
        "checkOnly" : false,
        "ignoreWarnings" : false,
        "performRetrieve" : false,
        "purgeOnDelete" : false,
        "rollbackOnError" : false,
        "runTests" : null,
        "singlePackage" : true,
        "testLevel" : "RunAllTestsInOrg"
    }
}

----------------------------BOUNDARY
Content-Type: application/zip
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename"deploy.zip"

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
----------------------------BOUNDARY--
```

### Question

What am I doing wrong?
Is there simpler approach to deploy some classes (which doesn't change) to Prod from Apex?
The solution should be lightweight, without using some heavy apex library.

Thanks!

Comment: if I answered your question, please consider marking it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest use SFDX CLI. It has `sfdx force:mdapi:deploy`, you don't need to zip package folder, only to pass path to it and login to the org.

Comment: Hi, I can't accept this answer, my requirement is to deploy using Apex. Thanks.

Comment: Why would you deploy your classes from APEX, Apex is not supposed to be used for Prod deployments

Comment: I'm working on a managed package, which needs two simple classes to live outside the package (to be without the namespace). This deployment should simplify the package configuration. Right now I achieved my goal with apex-mdapi project by FinancialForce.com, which is SOAP based, but it's a unnecessary heavy approach for such simple task. Another option is to deploy using Tooling API into a sandbox, then these classes can be deployed to production with whatever method, but this is one step more than it could be.

Comment: Well, I'm pretty sure if you only use classes in apex-mdapi you can strip it down to about 200-300 lines, but it would take some time) Cannot come up with better option now(
Regarding error, have you tried removing empty lines in your request?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't encode zip file with base64. There's no such requirement in [Deploy Metadata with Apex Testing Using REST](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_rest_deploy.htm). Base64 encoding is used in [SOAP api](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_deploy.htm), not REST.

This curl worked for me:

```
curl "${host}/services/data/v56.0/metadata/deployRequest" -X POST -H "Authorization: $auth" -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'Connection: Keep-Alive' -F 'json={ 
    "deployOptions" :
        {
        "allowMissingFiles" : false,
        "autoUpdatePackage" : false,
        "checkOnly" : false,
        "ignoreWarnings" : false,
        "performRetrieve" : false,
        "purgeOnDelete" : false,
        "rollbackOnError" : false,
        "runTests" : null,
        "singlePackage" : true,
        "testLevel" : "RunAllTestsInOrg"
        }
    };type=application/json; charset=US-ASCII' -F 'upload=@/tmp/meta.zip;type=application/zip; charset=US-ASCII' --compressed -k -v
```