# Deploy Metadata with Apex Testing Error

Tags: rest-api, deployment, metadata-api, static-resources, deployment-api

I am trying to deploy Omniscript which is stored in a zip file inside a static resource. I am following this documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_rest_deploy.htm).

**Here is the code** - `

public class MetadataDeploymentCurl {

```
public static HttpRequest makeDeploymentRequest(Blob zipFileBody) {
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setEndpoint('host'+'/services/data/v56.0/metadata/deployRequest');
    request.setMethod('POST');
    request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer 00D...');
    request.setHeader('Accept', '*/*');
    request.setHeader('Connection', 'Keep-Alive');
    request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
   
    String jsonPayload = '{' +
        '"deployOptions" : {' +
        '    "allowMissingFiles" : false,' +
        '    "autoUpdatePackage" : false,' +
        '    "checkOnly" : false,' +
        '    "ignoreWarnings" : false,' +
        '    "performRetrieve" : false,' +
        '    "purgeOnDelete" : false,' +
        '    "rollbackOnError" : false,' +
        '    "runTests" : null,' +
        '    "singlePackage" : false,' +
        '    "testLevel" : "NoTestRun"' +
        '}' +
    '}';        
    String boundary = '----Boundary-' + String.valueOf(Datetime.now().getTime());
    request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' + boundary);
    
    String body = '';
    
    // JSON Payload
    body += '--' + boundary + '\r\n';
    body += 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="entity_content"\r\n';
    body += 'Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n';
    body += jsonPayload + '\r\n';
    
    // ZIP File
    body += '--' + boundary + '\r\n';
    body += 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="unpackaged.zip"\r\n';
    body += 'Content-Type: application/zip\r\n\r\n';
    body += EncodingUtil.base64Encode(zipFileBody) + '\r\n';
    
    // Closing boundary
    body += '--' + boundary + '--';
    
    //request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' + boundary);
    request.setBodyasBLob(Blob.valueof(body));
    
    return request;
}
```

}`

**To invoke** -  `Blob zipFileBody = [SELECT Body FROM StaticResource WHERE Name = '<SRName>' LIMIT 1].Body;  HttpRequest deploymentRequest = MetadataDeploymentCurl.makeDeploymentRequest(zipFileBody); Http http = new Http(); HttpResponse response = http.send(deploymentRequest);`

Here is the **request body** generated -
[image]

In the response I can see 201 status code and the deployment being triggered. But in deployment if I keep singlePackage = true  then I get 'Payload error - No package.xml found'. And if I keep singlePackage = false, then deployment is succeeded but it shows 0/0 components in deployment window.

The zip file structure is this -
[image]

PS. - I tried with Postman using curl command mentioned in this [thread](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/326530/deploy-metadata-with-apex-testing-using-rest-error?newreg=6d79c2c15b79400ab98229e222f1bd11) and its working absolutely fine.

**Question**
What am I missing here? I have tried all the folder structure but still same issue. Is there any other approach that I can take to deploy the components from static resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few problems.

First, the ZIP file can't be base64 encoded. See [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/24137/2984) for a way to properly encode binary data in Apex Code. It's non-trivial because Apex doesn't have native binary support in the same sense that Java or C++ does.

Second, if you're setting `singlePackage` to `false`, you must have the following file structure:

```
+ package
| package.xml
| + omniScripts
  | scriptName.omniScript
```

I derived the script name from the [OmniScript](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_omniscript.htm) Metadata API object. It's not entirely clear, though, as few objects are formatted this way, so it may very well be a suffix of `.omniScript-meta.xml`. Either way, it's probably not `.os-meta.xml`.

Conversely, if you set `singlePackage` to true, the expected format is:

```
+ omniScripts
| scriptName.omniScript
package.xml
```

Notice how the package.xml must be at the base level, and metadata must be in their metadata folders (e.g. the `omniScripts` folder).